# SQL to SUM only positive numbers

Tags: sql, sum, numbers, sumifs

I have a a column of data that has both Positive and Negative numbers.  I need SQL to find and add only the positive values.

I am trying to add up Total Credits (Negative Number) and Total Debits (Positive Number) for a JE.  So I have a single column (AMOUNT) that has both Positive and Negative amounts.  In my TOTALCREDIT field I need code to tell it find and sum only the Positive numbers from the AMOUNT column and for the TOTALCREDIT field I need to find and add only the Negative numbers from the AMOUNT column. I have tried variations of the following but it always returns 0.

TOTALDEBIT

```
sum (case when AMOUNT >= 0 then AMOUNT else 0 end) as positive
```

TOTALCREDIT

```
sum (case when AMOUNT < 0 then AMOUNT else 0 end) as negative
```

So if the AMOUNT column has 25, -25, 30, -30

- The TOTALDEBIT field will sum to 55
- The TOTALCREDIT Field will sum to -55

So I need 1 of string code of for each field.

Comment: The parts of code you posted are correct. Post the full statement.

Comment: Instead of doing minus, can you do it directly sum (case when AMOUNT < 0 then AMOUNT else 0 end) as negative for credit ?

Comment: I tried that and it still returned 0.  I was thinking that maybe a I could have it SELECT all the positive values and then sum.     Or maybe create an if statement that says  SUM(IF AMOUNT is < 0 THEN AMOUNT else AMOUNT*0) that way it would turn all positives into 0.  I am just not familiar enough with SQL to write something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would join to itself

Transaction_Table =

- transaction_id
- customer_id
- Amount

---

Select

- x.customer_id
- SUM(cred.Amount) as TOTALCREDIT
- SUM(deb.Amount) AS TOTALDEBIT

FROM Transaction_Table x

LEFT JOIN Transaction_Table cred on x.transaction_id = cred.transaction_id and amount < 0

LEFT JOIN Transaction_Table deb on x.transaction_id = cred.transaction_id and amount >= 0

Group by x.customer_id

---

Or if you are looking the totals across the whole table just

Select

- SUM(cred.Amount) as TOTALCREDIT
- SUM(deb.Amount) AS TOTALDEBIT

FROM Transaction_Table x

LEFT JOIN Transaction_Table cred on x.transaction_id = cred.transaction_id and amount < 0

LEFT JOIN Transaction_Table deb on x.transaction_id = cred.transaction_id and amount >= 0